# Is jdk provided doubly linked list circular?

Tags: java

Is java  [doubly linked list](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html)  circular ?

It nowhere written in java docs. But looks likes its circular when i see linked list source code Here is the relevant code snippet if

```
private Entry<E> More ...entry(int index) {
...
        Entry<E> e = header;
        if (index < (size >> 1)) {
           ...
        } else {
             for (int i = size; i > index; i--)
                e = e.previous;
        }
        return e;
    }
```

**Update :-** By circular i mean

1. header previous node should be last node  which seems true here
2. And for last node next node should be header node

Comment: Circular in what sense? If you mean can you call `list.get(something)`, where `something >= list.size()`, [no](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#get-int-).

Comment: @AndyTurner please see my update

Comment: why do you actually care about internal implementation details? What are you *really* trying to do?

Comment: @AndyTurner maybe to know if we can jump from last to head or if the iterator can be repeated with `next`, or maybe just for extra knowledge ;)

Comment: Actually this is for learning

Comment: Then please take away the lesson: If something is not officially specified, but still implemented, stick to what's documented because implementations may change quickly.

Comment: Where does that code snippet come from anyway? My JDK apparently has LinkedList implemented differently.

Comment: @JimmyB i am looking at http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/LinkedList.java#LinkedList.size%28%29

Comment: Good! That perfectly supports my point :) My Sun/Oracle JDK has a different implementation of the same class, so if you did rely on the implementation details of one of the Java implementations your code would break when run on the other implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Going by your criteria

> 1. header previous node should be last node which seems true here
> 2. And  for last node next node should be header node

Linked list is circular because if you see `add` method [implementation](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/LinkedList.java#LinkedList.addBefore%28java.lang.Object%2Cjava.util.LinkedList.Entry%29) which internally calls `addBefore`, entry  you going to insert  points to header as next link and header points to last entry you just inserted as previous link

Answer (score -1):

It's not circular.  It has a clear Head and Tail.